# Setting environmental variables for node from host machine for build server

Tags: node.js, docker, build, environment-variables, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm using bitbucket pipelines as a build server.
I need to pass environmental variables from a host machine into a .env file which will then set the var values to be used in the build.

For example, lets say an environmental variable in a docker container running the build is AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID.

In my .env file I'd like something like the following:
ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}

I would then run the build and the ACCESS_KEY var would have a value equal to the env var in the docker container.

My current idea for a solution right now involves replacing values with sed, but that feels pretty hacky. Example:

.env file contains the following line:
ACCESS_KEY=<_access_key_replace_me_>

`sed "s/<_access_key_replace_me_>/${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}/g" .env`

Any better solution than this?

Comment: If you need to change the values dynamically, on-the-fly, using a script for text substitution is a Good Idea.  If you have the luxury of Linux shell scripting and sed - then why not?  It sounds like a great solution to me!

Comment: I was hoping there was a built in way to do it. I'm using the same idea in another pipeline for aws cloud formation. (DynamoDB deletion policies need to be set with sed as opposed to cloud formation vars.) The framework that I'm using on the backend (Micronaut - java) allows configuration files to use ${ENV_VAR} which pulls from the host machine at runtime

Comment: Better to pass access key as an system environment, system environment variables have high priority then dotenv

Comment: I'm assuming that by system environment variable you mean an env var on the host machine. How do I access a system environmental variable in a node js build without writing it to some kind of .env file?